# Ng Bootstrap accordion move to SharedModule - Angular

Tags: angular, accordion, ng-bootstrap

I have decided to move ng bootstrap components to the shared module to avoid the update in the feature.

My core component looks like below

```
<lib-sb-accordion>
  <lib-sb-accordion-panel>
    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon
            officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf
            moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim
            keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher
            vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't
            heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
  </lib-sb-accordion-panel>
</lib-sb-accordion>
```

My lib-sb-accordion component looks likes below

```
<ngb-accordion #acc="ngbAccordion">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</ngb-accordion>
```

My lib-sb-accordion-panel component looks likes below

```
<ngb-panel title="Simple">
  <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </ng-template>
</ngb-panel>
```

But nothing is rendered in the UI.

Could anyone help to resolve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you add it in SharedModule. Did you put it on export so that other modules that import your SharedModule can use the bootstrap modules.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Already exported that